# Login con password_verify() me dice que el usuario no existe

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy intentando sacar el hash de la base de datos de mi aplicación, pero este me dice que el usuario no existe, cuando está registrado.
Estoy usando el metodo password_verify(), seguro que se me pasa algo por alto, pego el código a continuación :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Formulario***

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Acceder</title>
  <!-- Fonts and icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900|Roboto+Slab:400,700" />
  <!-- Nucleo Icons -->
  <link href="front-end/css/nucleo-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="front-end/css/nucleo-svg.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/42d5adcbca.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Material Icons -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Round" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- CSS Files -->
  <link id="pagestyle" href="front-end/css/material-kit.css?v=3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="front-end/custom.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body class="sign-in-basic">
  <!-- Navbar Transparent -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg position-absolute top-0 z-index-3 w-100 shadow-none my-3 navbar-transparent">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-white">
        <img src="front-end/logos/LogoAgenda.png" alt="">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler shadow-none ms-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navigation" aria-controls="navigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon mt-2">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar1"></span>
          <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar2"></span>
          <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar3"></span>
        </span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100 pt-3 pb-2 py-lg-0 ms-lg-12 ps-lg-5" id="navigation">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-hover ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item ms-lg-auto">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-icon me-2" href="acceder.php">
              <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o me-1"></i>
              <p class="d-inline text-sm z-index-1 font-weight-bold">Acceder</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ms-lg-auto">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-icon me-2" href="registrarse.php">
              <i class="fa fa-user-plus me-1"></i>
              <p class="d-inline text-sm z-index-1 font-weight-bold">Registrarse</p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End Navbar -->
  <div class="page-header align-items-start min-vh-100" style="background-image: url('front-end/img/fondo-formularios.jpg');" loading="lazy">
    <span class="mask bg-gradient-dark opacity-6"></span>
    <div class="container my-auto">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-12 mx-auto">
          <div class="card fondo-login z-index-0 fadeIn3 fadeInBottom">
            <div class="card-header p-0 position-relative mt-n4 mx-3 z-index-2">
              <div class="fondo-del-titulo shadow-acceder border-radius-lg py-3 pe-1">
                <h4 class="text-white font-weight-bolder text-center mt-2 mb-0 titulo-de-form">Formulario de Acceso</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="text-center">
              <?php
              require_once 'back_end/conexion_de_bbdd/config_bd.php';
              if (isset($_SESSION["admin_login"])) {
                header("Location: panel_admin/inicio.php");
              }
              if (isset($_SESSION["colaborador_login"])) {
                header("Location: panel_colaborador/inicio.php");
              }
              if (isset($_SESSION["normal_login"])) {
                header("Location: panel/usuario.php");
              }

              $nombre = '';
              $password = '';
              $rol = '';

              if (isset($_POST['btn_login'])) {
                $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
                $password = $_POST["password"];
               
                $rol = $_POST["id_rol"];
                $_SESSION["usuario"] = $_POST["nombre"];

                if (empty($nombre)) {
                  $errorMsg[] = "Por favor ingrese Nombre"; //Revisar email
                } else if (empty($password)) {
                  $errorMsg[] = "Por favor ingrese Password"; //Revisar password vacio
                } else if (empty($rol)) {
                  $errorMsg[] = "Por favor seleccione Rol "; //Revisar rol vacio
                } else if ($nombre and $password and $rol) {
                  try {
                    $select_stmt = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_rol=:urol AND nombre=:unombre AND password=:upassword");
                    $select_stmt->bindParam(":unombre", $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $select_stmt->bindParam(":upassword", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $select_stmt->bindParam(":urol", $rol, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $select_stmt->execute();



                    while ($fila_usuarios = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                      $bdnombre = $fila_usuarios["nombre"];
                      // $bdpassword = $fila_usuarios["password"];

                      if (password_verify($bdpassword, $fila_usuarios["password"])) {
                        return true;
                      } else {
                        return false;
                      }

                      $bdrol = $fila_usuarios["id_rol"];
                    }


                    //Descomentar en caso de error
                    $select_stmt->debugDumpParams();
                    var_dump($fila_usuarios);

                    if ($nombre != null & $password  != null & $rol != null) {
                      if ($select_stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                        if ($nombre == $bdnombre & $password == $bdpassword &  $rol == $bdrol) {
                           switch ($bdrol) {
                            case "1":
                              $_SESSION["admin_login"] = $nombre;
                              $_SESSION["admin_login"] = $rol;

                              $loginMsg = "Inicio sesión con éxito";
                              header("refresh:3; panel_admin/inicio.php");
                              break;

                            case "2";
                              $_SESSION["colaborador_login"] = $nombre;
                              $_SESSION["colaborador_login"] = $rol;
                              $loginMsg = "Inicio sesión con éxito";
                              header("refresh:3; panel_colaborador/inicio.php");
                              break;

                            case "3":
                              $_SESSION["normal_login"] = $nombre;
                              $_SESSION["normal_login"] = $rol;
                              $loginMsg = "Inicio sesión con éxito";
                              header("refresh:3; panel_usuario/inicio.php");
                              break;

                            default:
                              $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                          }
                        } else {
                          $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                        }
                      } else {
                        $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                      }
                    } else {
                      $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                    }
                  } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    echo "Error : ".$e->getMessage();
                    echo "Linea : ".$e->getLine();
                  }
                } else {
                  $errorMsg[] = "El nombre o contraseña o rol incorrectos";
                }
              }
              ?>
            <div class="card-body">
              <form role="form" class="text-start" method="POST">
                <div class="input-group input-group-dynamic mb-4 my-3">
                  <i class="fa fa-user form-icons-acceder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control inputs-tipo-letra" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if (isset($nombre)) echo $nombre ?>">
                </div>

                <div class="input-group input-group-dynamic mb-4 my-3">
                  <i class="fa fa-key form-icons-acceder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control inputs-tipo-letra" placeholder="Contraseña" value="<?php if (isset($password)) echo $password ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">

                  <div class="input-group input-group-dynamic input-group-custom">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog form-icons-acceder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <select name="id_rol" id="id_rol" class="form-select form-select-custom-acceder" onChange="imprimirValor()">
                      <option>Selecciona un rol</option>
                      <?php
                      $query_rol = $bd->query("SELECT id_rol,privilegios FROM rol AS rol WHERE rol.privilegios = 'Administrador' OR rol.privilegios = 'Colaborador' OR rol.privilegios = 'Normal';");
                      $resultado_tipo_rol = $query_rol->fetchAll();

                      foreach ($resultado_tipo_rol as $roles) {
                      ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $roles["id_rol"]; ?>" <?php if ($roles["id_rol"] == $rol) {
                                                                          echo 'selected="selected"';
                                                                        } ?>>
                          <?php echo $roles["privilegios"]; ?>
                        </option>
                      <?php
                      }
                      ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center">
                  <input class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-secondary my-3" type="submit" name="btn_login" value="Iniciar Sesión" />
                </div>

                <p class="mt-4 text-sm text-center texto-normal">
                  No tienes cuenta ?
                  <a href="registrarse.php" class="text-success text-gradient font-weight-bold texto-normal">Registrate</a>
                </p>
                <hr>


                <small class="text-muted texto-para-verificar">
                  <?php
                  if (isset($errorMsg)) {
                    foreach ($errorMsg as $error) {
                  ?>
                      <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong class="text-dark"><?php echo $error; ?></strong>
                      </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                  }
                  if (isset($loginMsg)) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                      <strong class="text-dark"><?php echo $loginMsg; ?> </strong>
                    </div>
                  <?php
                  }
                  ?>
                </small>
                </p>
              </form>
              <?php
              if ($bd == true) {
                echo "<p class='text-center estado-de-la-conexion'>
                            Aplicación conectada. <i class='fa fa-check-circle text-success' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                      </p>";
              }
              ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <script src="front-end/js/core/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="front-end/js/core/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="front-end/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="front-end/js/plugins/parallax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="front-end/js/material-kit.min.js?v=3.0.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

***Error :***

```
SQL: [85] SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_rol=:urol AND nombre=:unombre AND password=:upassword Sent SQL: [85] SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_rol=1 AND nombre='test3_encriptado' AND password=NULL Params: 3 Key: Name: [8] :unombre paramno=-1 name=[8] ":unombre" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [10] :upassword paramno=-1 name=[10] ":upassword" is_param=1 param_type=0 Key: Name: [5] :urol paramno=-1 name=[5] ":urol" is_param=1 param_type=1 bool(false)
```

Comment: se almacena en hash te lo muestro en una imagen adjunta arriba

Comment: El valor que envías desde el formulario es texto plano y lo que almacenas en la base de datos esta hasheado, por ende dicha comparación será falsa y como colocaste que todas se cumplan es lógico que te indique que el usuario no existe.

Answer (score -2):

La solución fue sencilla al final lo que tuve que indicarle en las variables el tipo de encriptación que deseaba añadir al registro y de igual manera al login, incluso le he puesto la propiedad ***htmlspecialchars*** para evitar injección sql, dejo el script a continuación :

Tanto en el log como en el registro :

**$password = md5(htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]));**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Acceder</title>
  <!-- Fonts and icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900|Roboto+Slab:400,700" />
  <!-- Nucleo Icons -->
  <link href="front-end/css/nucleo-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="front-end/css/nucleo-svg.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/42d5adcbca.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Material Icons -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Round" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- CSS Files -->
  <link id="pagestyle" href="front-end/css/material-kit.css?v=3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="front-end/custom.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body class="sign-in-basic">
  <!-- Navbar Transparent -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg position-absolute top-0 z-index-3 w-100 shadow-none my-3 navbar-transparent">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-white">
        <img src="front-end/logos/LogoAgenda.png" alt="">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler shadow-none ms-2" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navigation" aria-controls="navigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon mt-2">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar1"></span>
          <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar2"></span>
          <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar3"></span>
        </span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100 pt-3 pb-2 py-lg-0 ms-lg-12 ps-lg-5" id="navigation">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-hover ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item ms-lg-auto">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-icon me-2" href="acceder.php">
              <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o me-1"></i>
              <p class="d-inline text-sm z-index-1 font-weight-bold">Acceder</p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ms-lg-auto">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-icon me-2" href="registrarse.php">
              <i class="fa fa-user-plus me-1"></i>
              <p class="d-inline text-sm z-index-1 font-weight-bold">Registrarse</p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End Navbar -->
  <div class="page-header align-items-start min-vh-100" style="background-image: url('front-end/img/fondo-formularios.jpg');" loading="lazy">
    <span class="mask bg-gradient-dark opacity-6"></span>
    <div class="container my-auto">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-12 mx-auto">
          <div class="card fondo-login z-index-0 fadeIn3 fadeInBottom">
            <div class="card-header p-0 position-relative mt-n4 mx-3 z-index-2">
              <div class="fondo-del-titulo shadow-acceder border-radius-lg py-3 pe-1">
                <h4 class="text-white font-weight-bolder text-center mt-2 mb-0 titulo-de-form">Formulario de Acceso</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="text-center">
              <?php
              require_once 'back_end/conexion_de_bbdd/config_bd.php';
              if (isset($_SESSION["admin_login"])) {
                header("Location: panel_admin/inicio.php");
              }
              if (isset($_SESSION["colaborador_login"])) {
                header("Location: panel_colaborador/inicio.php");
              }
              if (isset($_SESSION["normal_login"])) {
                header("Location: panel/usuario.php");
              }

              $nombre = '';
              $password = '';
              $rol = '';

              if (isset($_POST['btn_login'])) {
                $nombre = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nombre"]);
                $password = md5(htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]));
                $rol = htmlspecialchars($_POST["id_rol"]);
                $_SESSION["usuario"] = $_POST["nombre"];

                if (empty($nombre)) {
                  $errorMsg[] = "Por favor ingrese Nombre"; //Revisar email
                } else if (empty($password)) {
                  $errorMsg[] = "Por favor ingrese Password"; //Revisar password vacio
                } else if (empty($rol)) {
                  $errorMsg[] = "Por favor seleccione Rol "; //Revisar rol vacio
                } else if ($nombre and $password and $rol) {
                  try {
                    $select_stmt = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_rol=:urol AND nombre=:unombre AND password=:upassword");
                    $select_stmt->bindParam(":unombre", $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $select_stmt->bindParam(":upassword", $password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $select_stmt->bindParam(":urol", $rol, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $select_stmt->execute();

                    while ($fila_usuarios = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                      $bdnombre = $fila_usuarios["nombre"];
                      $bdpassword = $fila_usuarios["password"];
                      $bdrol = $fila_usuarios["id_rol"];
                    }


                    //Descomentar en caso de error
                    // $select_stmt->debugDumpParams();
                    // var_dump($fila_usuarios);

                    if ($nombre != null & $password  != null & $rol != null) {
                      if ($select_stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                        if ($nombre == $bdnombre & $password == $bdpassword &  $rol == $bdrol) {
                           switch ($bdrol) {
                            case "1":
                              $_SESSION["admin_login"] = $nombre;
                              $_SESSION["admin_login"] = $rol;

                              $loginMsg = "Inicio sesión con éxito";
                              header("refresh:3; panel_admin/inicio.php");
                              break;

                            case "2";
                              $_SESSION["colaborador_login"] = $nombre;
                              $_SESSION["colaborador_login"] = $rol;
                              $loginMsg = "Inicio sesión con éxito";
                              header("refresh:3; panel_colaborador/inicio.php");
                              break;

                            case "3":
                              $_SESSION["normal_login"] = $nombre;
                              $_SESSION["normal_login"] = $rol;
                              $loginMsg = "Inicio sesión con éxito";
                              header("refresh:3; panel_usuario/inicio.php");
                              break;

                            default:
                              $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                          }
                        } else {
                          $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                        }
                      } else {
                        $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                      }
                    } else {
                      $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                    }
                  } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    echo "Error : ".$e->getMessage();
                    echo "Linea : ".$e->getLine();
                  }
                } else {
                  $errorMsg[] = "El nombre o contraseña o rol incorrectos";
                }
              }
              ?>
            <div class="card-body">
              <form role="form" class="text-start" method="POST">
                <div class="input-group input-group-dynamic mb-4 my-3">
                  <i class="fa fa-user form-icons-acceder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control inputs-tipo-letra" placeholder="Nombre">
                </div>

                <div class="input-group input-group-dynamic mb-4 my-3">
                  <i class="fa fa-key form-icons-acceder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control inputs-tipo-letra" placeholder="Contraseña">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">

                  <div class="input-group input-group-dynamic input-group-custom">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog form-icons-acceder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <select name="id_rol" id="id_rol" class="form-select form-select-custom-acceder" onChange="imprimirValor()">
                      <option>Selecciona un rol</option>
                      <?php
                      $query_rol = $bd->query("SELECT id_rol,privilegios FROM rol AS rol WHERE rol.privilegios = 'Administrador' OR rol.privilegios = 'Colaborador' OR rol.privilegios = 'Normal';");
                      $resultado_tipo_rol = $query_rol->fetchAll();

                      foreach ($resultado_tipo_rol as $roles) {
                      ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $roles["id_rol"]; ?>" <?php if ($roles["id_rol"] == $rol) {
                                                                          echo 'selected="selected"';
                                                                        } ?>>
                          <?php echo $roles["privilegios"]; ?>
                        </option>
                      <?php
                      }
                      ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center">
                  <input class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-secondary my-3" type="submit" name="btn_login" value="Iniciar Sesión" />
                </div>

                <p class="mt-4 text-sm text-center texto-normal">
                  No tienes cuenta ?
                  <a href="registrarse.php" class="text-success text-gradient font-weight-bold texto-normal">Registrate</a>
                </p>
                <hr>


                <small class="text-muted texto-para-verificar">
                  <?php
                  if (isset($errorMsg)) {
                    foreach ($errorMsg as $error) {
                  ?>
                      <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong class="text-dark"><?php echo $error; ?></strong>
                      </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                  }
                  if (isset($loginMsg)) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                      <strong class="text-dark"><?php echo $loginMsg; ?> </strong>
                    </div>
                  <?php
                  }
                  ?>
                </small>
                </p>
              </form>
              <?php
              if ($bd == true) {
                echo "<p class='text-center estado-de-la-conexion'>
                            Aplicación conectada. <i class='fa fa-check-circle text-success' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                      </p>";
              }
              ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer position-absolute bottom-2 py-2 w-100">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-lg-between">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-auto">
            <div class="copyright text-center text-sm text-white text-lg-start">
              © <script>
                document.write(new Date().getFullYear())
              </script>,
              Desarrollado por <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> by
              <a href="#" class="font-weight-bold text-white" target="_blank">Milanés</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <ul class="nav nav-footer justify-content-center justify-content-lg-end">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#p" class="nav-link text-white" target="_blank">PortFolio</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="front-end/js/core/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="front-end/js/core/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="front-end/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="front-end/js/plugins/parallax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="front-end/js/material-kit.min.js?v=3.0.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yo no usaría ```md5``` para encriptar tus contraseñas, ya que es nada seguro, usaría ```password_hash()``` como lo estabas haciendo y como te habían dejado ya una respuesta, luego respecto a ```htmlspecialchars```, esto no evita la inyección SQL, te dejo un enlace al respecto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php/53134#53134